# mysql update random a column (fast)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random, sql-update

How can you randomly update a table. So you give a column a random value. And the column (in example 'top') is unique. And if you choose between the numbers 10 to 20 and you have 10 rows that you can't have a number that isn't used. If you have

```
Test table
-Id-    -Top-
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
```

Change randomly the column 'top' (1 to 4)

```
Test table
-Id-    -Top-
0        4
1        1
2        3
3        2
```

If I use PHP it is very slow. But MySQL is fast.
I don't use SELECT because I also need to save the answers.
Can anyone help me? thanks a lot.

Mysql: 5.7.22

PHP: 7.2.7

I use Mysql PDO lib for PHP.

Comment: Don't do this in MySQL, use a proper programming language to generate these numbers. Use sql only for the update part.

Comment: But that is very slow if I use PHP.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: My mysql version is 5.7.22

Comment: See if it works for your mysql version and let me know so I will add it as an answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/053eb0/4

Comment: A "random" value is not "unique".

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jorge campos. I tested it on PhpMyAdmin. Only 2 changes rand(id) to rand(:randomvalue), because if you don't do that you get always the same answers. My php script can choose a random value for :randomvalue. And not select but update. (is it possible to update the database with the select result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to assign a sequential number arbitrarily to rows, you can use variables:

```
set @rn := 0;

update t
    set top = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by rand();
```

The assignment looks sequential, but the `order by rand()` means that the values are inserted on random rows.  All the numbers are unique because they are sequential.